# How do I check for multiple exceptions in Python?

Tags: exception, python-2.6

DNASequence = "laksjfklsajdfklsajfklasjfklsad"

```
    while True:
        lMerLength = input("Please enter the length of the l-mers of the universal array :")
        try:
            if len(DNASequence) >= lMerLength > 0:
                break
        except SyntaxError:
            pass
        #This is not working. How do I check for multiple exceptions in Python?
        except NameError:
            pass
        print "ERROR: Please check your input. You entered an invalid input."
```

Comment: "This is not working": Why does it not work? Do you get any exceptions? Unexpected behavior? BTW: Why do you handle a `SyntaxError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you check for multiple exceptions.

try:

```
    ..............
```

except (SyntaxError, NameError, ...):

```
    ..............
```

finally:

```
    .............
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `input` returns a string and you compare that string in your if to an int. And in python 2.x you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`:

```
DNASequence = "laksjfklsajdfklsajfklasjfklsad"
while True:
    try:
        lMerLength = int(raw_input("Please enter the length of the l-mers of the universal array :"))
    except ValueError:
        print "ERROR: Please check your input. You entered an invalid input."
        continue
    if len(DNASequence) >= lMerLength > 0:
        break
    print "ERROR: Please check your input. You entered an invalid input."
```